# why a "char*" can point to a "const char*"?

Tags: c, char, constants

the following code can be compiled correctly on both VC or gcc:

```
char *str = "I am a const!";
str[2] = 'n';
```

however, obviously there is a run-time-error. Since "I am a const!" is a *const char**, why the compiler doesn't give an error or even a warning ??

---

Besides, if I define `char a[] = "I am const!"`, all the elements in `a` can be modified, why this time the string literals become `nonconst` ?

Comment: Because in C, string literals are not (as you assert) `const char *`s. (In C++ they're also not `const char *`s. They're arrays, not pointers, and in one they're `const`.)

Comment: What compiler are you using? In gcc, set the warning flag `-Wwrite-strings`

Comment: sorry, but on my redhat, gcc prompts "cc1: unrecognized option `-Wfixed-strings' "

Comment: @Flybywind ooh was unaware -- you may need to update GCC :P

Comment: I +1'd this because I thought I saw this option before. However gcc 4.5 doesn't accept it.

Comment: The flag is `-Wwrite-strings`. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as C is concerned, that string literal is not const, it's a `char[14]` which you assign to a char*, which is perfectly fine.

However, C does say that changing a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 but it should be noted that the confusion probably comes from C++, where string literals _are_ `const`.

Comment: I still can't understand, since the string literals are just char[], not const, then why I can't change the value ?

Comment: @Flybywind: Because the language says so. The specification of C language clearly says that string literals are not modifiable, even though they are not `const`.

Comment: It's because const was backported to C from C++. String literals were immutable before const was invented.

Comment: @okorz001: ok, if we define a variable like this `char a[] = "I am a const!"`, all elements in `a` can be changed, why the rule above vanishes at this situation ?

Comment: @Flybywind: In that case, it is because the string literal is an array initializer.  It is equivalent to `char a[] = { 'I', ' ', 'a', 'm'...`

Comment: @Flybywind That creates an array, and initializes that array from the string literal. You can change the array, just like any other array you have - there's a big difference between a char* and a char array.

Comment: @Flybywind It's about ownership of the data. When you have `char a[] = "..."`, the string is in the memory range allocated to `a`. When you have `char *str = "..."` the string is in some implementation defined location which `str` receives a pointer to. You are not allowed to modify `*str` because compiler is allowed to do tricks with these locations. For example, I know in C++ the compiler can overlap common substrings (I'm not sure if this is ok in C).